# How to active class click function after using 'createElement'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to active function when clicking on button which is created with `createElement`.

On html code:

```
<fieldset class="form-fieldset">
   <button type="button" class="btn-ref">Hello</button>
</fieldset>
```

On javascript:

```
$('.btn-ref').click(function(){
   var newButton = document.createElement('button');
   newButton.className="btn-ref";
   $('.form-fieldset').append(newButton);
});
```

On original code, when clicking on button does create new button. But after clicking on created button, it does not create new button.

Can someone tell me what is wrong?

Comment: because events do not magically become connected....

Comment: Use something like `$("body").on("click", ".btn-ref", function(){....})` to have a listener that works on dynamically created elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add button name by getting its value `textContent :- returns the text content of the specified node value`.

It will find on body where this className used will createElement dynamically and applies value to it.

```js
$("body").on("click", ".btn-ref", function(event) {
    var newButton = document.createElement('button');
    newButton.className = "btn-ref";
    newButton.textContent = $(this).text();
    $('.form-fieldset').append(newButton);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset class="form-fieldset">
    <button type="button" class="btn-ref">Hello</button>
</fieldset>
```